Kiam ke-frazo ne estas parolo nerekta?
Jen estas frazoj simplaj, en kiuj estas parolo nerekta.

Mi rimarkis, ke ŝi preparas manĝon.
Li diris, ke ri venos je semajno poste.

La tempo de tia ke-frazo estas relativa al tiu de la ĉeffrazo, ĉar en tia frazo estas parolo nerekta...sed kiam (se iam ajn) ne estas tiel? Alivorte, kiam la tempo de ke-frazo ne estas relativa al tiu de la ĉeffrazo? Mi demandas, ĉar mi volas fari esprimon kiel, ekzemple

Antaŭ longe, dum la Epoĥo de la Monadoj, estis tiel, ke ĉiu homo mem iutage fariĝos monado.

aŭ

Tiu monado estis tia, ke preskaŭ ĉiu ĝin volas tuŝi.

kaj tiel plu.
Anstataŭ "[...] estis tiel, ke [...]", mi povus diri "[...] ĉiu homo mem estis iutage fariĝonta monado" sen meza frazo, kaj simile por la alia. Tamen, mia demando temas specife pri tio, ĉu "esti tiel/tia, ke" (kaj tiaj frazeroj) povas enkonduki parolon nerektan, kaj ĉu la tempo ankaŭ tiuokaze estas relativa al tiu de la ĉeffrazo.

Eble mi ne komprenas vian demandon, sed en viaj ekzemploj vi ne bezonas tiujn "mezajn" frazojn. Alivorte vi povas skribi: "Antaŭ longe dum la Epoĥo de la Monadoj ĉiu homo mem iutage fariĝis monado." Temas ja pri pasinta tempo.

"Estis [iutage] fariĝonta" ne nepre signifas "[iutage] fariĝis". Eble, io okazis kaj neniu fariĝis monado (fakte, ĝuste tial mi uzis "estis fariĝonta" en ekzemplo).

Ĉiuokaze, mia demando ne temas pri tio.

Nerekta parolo (laŭ PMEG):

Nerekta parolo estas subfrazo, kiu rerakontas ies diron, penson, opinion, decidon, demandon, rimarkon k.s.

Surbaze de tiu difino, mi pensas ke la jenaj Fundamentaj ekzemplaj ke-subfrazoj respondas vian demandon kaj ili devus permesi eltiri pli ĝeneralajn konkludojn:

Li vekiĝis per tio, ke iu lin skuis.
Estis tia ventego, ke la tegoloj deflugis de la tegmentoj.



mia demando temas specife pri tio, ĉu "esti tiel/tia, ke" (kaj tiaj
frazeroj) povas enkonduki parolon nerektan

Ne
